# RDF format output from Fuseki 1.0

Tags: jena, fuseki, apache-jena

I am using the Apache Jena Fuseki version 1.0, which provides ability to use SPARQL query to get the data in text, JSON and XML format. Whether Fuseki 1.0 supports RDF output format? If possible, please tell how to get output in RDF format from Fuseki 1.0.

Comment: Fuseki1 is old and being retired in favour of Fuseki2.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for a result set (SELECT query) the output is one of the result set formats.

If you want RDF, use a CONSTRUCT query.